# Applying a function with arguments to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a percentile dataframe `df` as follows:

```
            col1   col2   col3      
GDStart                                                                   
2019-09-02  100    11     12  
2019-09-03   60    16     14  
2019-09-04   60    67     13
```

and an external function as:

```
import numpy as np
def Fn(x, a):
 return np.percentile(x, a)
```

I want to get apply my custom `Fn` to each row of `df` to get median for each row. I am expecting the following answer when using np.percentile(x, 50) i.e. median for each row:

```
         col1
GDStart                                                                   
2019-09-02   12
2019-09-03   16
2019-09-04   60
```

I am not sure how to apply the `lambda` or `apply` function here. My situation is tricky as I might need to find 30th percentile, or 50th percentile etc; `a` changes.

Comment: If you want `median` I suspect you meant to use `quantile` in `Fn` and not `percentile`

Comment: Unless you're doing something else on top - will `df.median(axis=1)` not work here?

Comment: @JonClements I suspect they want to understand the mechanics of how to pass other arguments to the function being applied... which I'm looking for the dup now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pass the keywords to `apply`

It will pass it along to the function

```
df.apply(Fn, a=.5, axis=1)
```

---

#### Pass the positional arguments

```
df.apply(Fn, args=(.5,), axis=1)
```